# calculate the day of the year c++

Tags: c++

I'm new in programming and I'm currently taking *C++*.

For example, if the `year` entered is below `1583`, but `month` and `day` value is within range, then the program will display error message. However, if the `year` value is above `1582`, but the `month` or the `day` value is out of range, then it will still proceed to calculate the `day` of the `year`.

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void showOption();
bool validMonth (int month);
bool validYear (int year);
bool leapYear (int year);
bool validDay (int year, int month, int day);
void getData (int& month, int& day, int& year);
void easterDate (int& month, int& day, int& year);
int daysBetween (int month1, int day1, int month2, int day2, int year);
int dayOfYear (int day, int month, int year);

const int january = 31;
const int february = 28;
const int leapYearFeb = 29;
const int march = 31;
const int april = 30;
const int may = 31;
const int june =30;
const int july = 31;
const int august = 31;
const int september = 30;
const int october = 31;
const int november = 30;
const int decemebr = 31;

int main()
{
    int option;
    int day, month, year;
    int easterDay, easterMonth;
    int day1, day2, month1, month2;

    bool repeat = false;

    showOption();

    cout << "please enter your option: ";
    cin >> option;
    cout << "" << endl;

    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:

            do
            {
                getData(month, day, year);

                validDay(year, month, day);

                if(validDay(year, month, day) == true)
                {
                    cout << "month " << month << " day " << day << " year " << year << endl;
                    cout << " " << endl;
                    cout << "They day of the year based on the date you entered is "<< dayOfYear(day, month, year) << endl;
                    cout << " " << endl;
                }
                else
                {

                    cout << "it is not a valid date." << endl;
                }


                cout << "do you still want to continue?" << endl;
                cout << "0 = no.     1 = yes.     ";
                cin >> repeat;
                cout << " " << endl;

            } while(repeat);

            break;
        case 2:

            do
            {

                cout << "do you still want to continue?" << endl;
                cout << "0 = no.     1 = yes.     ";
                cin >> repeat;

            } while(repeat);

            break;

        case 3:

            do
            {

                cout << "do you still want to continue?" << endl;
                cout << "0 = no.     1 = yes.     ";
                cin >> repeat;

            } while(repeat);

            break;
    }

}

void showOption()
{
    cout << " ------------------MENU------------------ " << endl;
    cout << " 1) Day of the year." << endl;
    cout << " 2) Date of Easter day." << endl;
    cout << " 3) Number of days between 2 days entered." << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
}

bool validMonth (int month)
{
    if (month > 0 || month < 13)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool validYear (int year)
{
    if (year > 1582)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool leapYear (int year)
{
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void getData (int& month, int& day, int& year)
{
    cout << "enter the number of year: ";
            cin >> year;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << "enter the number of month: ";
            cin >> month;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << "enter the number of day: ";
            cin >> day;
            cout << "" << endl;
}

bool validDay (int year, int month, int day)
{
    if(year > 1582)
    {
        if(validMonth(month))
        {
            if((month == 1) || (month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) || (month || 8) || (month == 10) || (month || 12))
            {
                if((day > 0) || (day < 32))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            if((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11))
            {
                if((day > 0) || (day < 31))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            if(month == 2)
            {
                if((day > 0) || (day < 29))     
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            if((leapYear(year)))
            {
                if((month == 2) && ((day > 0) || (day < 30)))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}


int dayOfYear (int day, int month, int year)
{
    int dayTotal = 0;

    if(validDay(year, month, day))
    {
        if(month == 1)
        {
            dayTotal = 0 + day;
        }

        if(month == 2)
        {
            dayTotal = january + day;
        }

        if((month == 3) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + day;

            if((month == 3) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + day;
            }
        }

        if((month == 4) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + march + day;

            if((month == 4) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + march + day;
            }
        }

        if((month == 5) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + march + april + day;

            if((month == 5) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + march + april + day;
            }
        }

        if((month == 6) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + day;

            if((month == 6) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + march + april + may + day;
            }
        }

        if((month == 7) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + day;

            if((month == 7) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + march + april + may + june + day;
            }
        }

        if((month == 8) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + day;

            if((month == 8) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + march + april + may + june + july + day;
            }
        }

        if((month == 9) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august 
                       + day;

            if((month == 9) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + march + april + may + june + july + august 
                       + day;
            }
        }

        if((month == 10) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august 
                       + september + day;

            if((month == 10) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + march + april + may + june + july + august
                       + september + day;
            }
        }

        if((month == 11) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august 
                       + september + october + day;

            if((month == 11) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + march + april + may + june + july + august 
                       + september + october + day;
            }
        }

        if((month == 12) && (year > 1582))
        {
            dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august
                       + september + october + november + day;

            if((month == 5) && (year > 1582) && (leapYear(year)))
            {
                dayTotal = january + leapYearFeb + march + april + may + june + july + august
                       + september + october + november + day;
            }
        }
    }

    return dayTotal;
}
```

It compile but the output is not correct.

### Question:

I need help and wonder if someone can take a look at my code and tell me what is wrong with it?

Note: I have been working in this code for 2 days and I cant figure out what I did wrong. I really appreciate your help and feedback. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the error message you are getting.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you. omg, I didn't even notice that error. The weird thing is my code compile even with the error that you mention. Its just that the output of my program is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

You're using many disjunctions ("or", `||`) where you should use conjunctions ("and", `&&`).
For instance, `month > 0 || month < 13` is true for a `month` of -10 or 1432.

There are also some places where a `||` should be `==`.

Comment: Thank you for point that out for me. I already correct it. I wonder what is wrong with my logic.

Comment: Thank you for point that out for me. I already correct it. I wonder what is wrong with my logic. for example, for a leap year, there will be 366 days. So, If I type in year 2000, month 12, and day 31. I supposed to get 366 days. it is only shows 365 days. not only that . If I type in year 2000, month 2, day 30. I supposed to get error message but instead it calculate and shows there are 61 days.

Comment: @tooDumbtoBeProgrammer If it's December, you only use the "leap year February" if it's also May. I think you may have done a bit too much copy-and-pasting. Tip: Chain the calculation like this: Start with the date. If it's later than January, add `january`; if it's also later than February, add the correct days for February; if it's also later than March, add `march`, and so on.

Comment: @milbdnilo      Yes. I finally notice that. Thank you for correcting me. I am still working on the output error. The weird thing is my code is able to compiled. it does not show error message.

Comment: @tooDumbtoBeProgrammer There's nothing weird about that. The compiler can't guess what you *intend* the code to do and let you know if you're wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Month length implement as

```
const int month_lenght [ 31,28,31 ... ];
```

Warning: january here==0, that problem is present in Java Date january=0 but day 1=first. So alternative can be:

```
const int month_lenght [ 0 /*dummy*/  31,28,31 ... ];
```

then no

```
    if(month == 1)
    {
        dayTotal = 0 + day;
    }

    if(month == 2)
    {
        dayTotal = january + day;
    }
```

but `for` loop.

if is required only for February and leap year

EDIT: agree, errors with && and ||

EDIT2:
probably

```
void easterDate (int& month, int& day, int& year);
```

change declaration, maybe to:

```
void easterDate (int& month /* out */, int& day /*out */ , int year /* in */);
```

BTW all world except english-USA culture think (and compute) y/m/d or d/m/y

Comment: yeah I've never seen a library function that lists arguments in m/d/y order

Comment: Well, this is my second school assignment. As for array thing, I haven't learn it yet. That is why I don't  use array. Thank you for your feedback